# Why do newer versions of GNU `ls` have different output in command substitution when dealing with newlines?

Tags: ls, gnu

The folder "/tmp/folder" contains one file, whose filename consists only of a single newline.

The output of `ls -A /tmp/folder`, even inside a non-interactive script, is:

```
''$'\n'
```

Here are the contents of script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh --

var="$(ls -A /tmp/folder; printf x)"

var="${var%x}"

printf '%s' "$var"
```

The output of script.sh is two empty lines.

Maybe GNU `ls` can detect if it is being run inside of a command substitution or is being redirected to file?

Comment: "inside a non-interactive script" ... But still outputting to a terminal, I'd bet

Comment: The word "can" on the last line, does it mean "should" or is the question "Can GNU `ls` detect ..."?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, I meant "Can GNU `ls` detect..."? Thanks @muru for pointing me to the right answer